# Accessing Sharepoint resources fails with internal-server error 503

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am calling this API in MS Graph Explorer to access Sharepoint:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root`

It fails with error 503:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Proxy_InternalServerError",
        "message": "Failure in forwarding request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a9b1cc4e-5ba9-46e2-aa6c-7592d6bd4f7c",
            "date": "2019-10-18T19:28:41"
        }
    }
}
```

This is in AAD tenant microsoft.com.

How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was a transient service failure.